# Extracting image subset (cropping) with SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, skiasharp, skia

I am trying to re-purpose [an example from GitHub](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1059#issuecomment-566575701) that deals with cropping an image with SkiaSharp. Specifically, I have a 4096x4096 sprite sheet from which I'd like to extract a sub-image (a specific sprite, if you will). To do that, I use the following snippet (where `spriteContent` is a byte array of the PNG image - `byte[]`):

```cs
var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(spriteContent, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    var addr = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    using var pixmap = new SkiaSharp.SKPixmap(info, addr);
    SkiaSharp.SKRectI rectI = new SkiaSharp.SKRectI(0, 0, 256, 256);

    var subset = pixmap.ExtractSubset(rectI);

    using var data = subset.Encode(SkiaSharp.SKPngEncoderOptions.Default)

    File.WriteAllBytes("test2.png", data.ToArray());
}
finally
{
    gch.Free();
}
```

The output of this code is, however, this kind of image:

[image: Malformed PNG image]

Seems like an odd output. I suspect that I am doing something funky with teh `SKRectI` declaration, where the *true* rectangle is never used. What I understand it to be doing is create a rectangle from point 0 on top, 0 on bottom, 256 pixels tall, 256 pixels wide (i.e., manage the selection). If I adjust this to, let's say:

```cs
SkiaSharp.SKRectI rectI = new SkiaSharp.SKRectI(256, 256, 256, 256);
```

I get a `NullReferenceException` and there is nothing in the subset, so I must be misinterpreting how the rectangle selector works.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noise you get is caused by the fact, that you reinterpret raw encoded png bytes as pixel data. You need to decode the image first:

```
using var skBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(spriteContent);

using var pixmap =  new SKPixmap(skBitmap.Info, skBitmap.GetPixels());
SkiaSharp.SKRectI rectI = new SkiaSharp.SKRectI(0, 0, 256, 256);

var subset = pixmap.ExtractSubset(rectI);

using var data = subset.Encode(SkiaSharp.SKPngEncoderOptions.Default);

File.WriteAllBytes(@"test2.png", data.ToArray());
```